Factoring of events that are only independent conditioned on a set of measure zero
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ denote a probability space and $ \{F_x : \Omega \to \mathbb R\ |\ x \in \mathcal X \}$ an independent stochastic process, i.e. for any $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathcal X$ the random variables
$F_{x_1}, \ldots F_{x_n}$ satisfy $\mathbb P[F_{x_1} \in \mathcal A_1, \ldots, F_{x_n} \in \mathcal A_n] = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P[F_{x_i} \in \mathcal A_i]$ for any Borel sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n \subseteq \mathbb R$. Then conditional independence follows easily, i.e.
$$ \mathbb P[Z_2 \in \mathcal A_2, \ldots, Z_n \in \mathcal A_n | Z_1 \in \mathcal A_1]  = \prod_{i=2}^n \mathbb P[Z_i \in \mathcal A_i] $$
for any Borel sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n \subseteq \mathbb R$. Now what I am interested in is the following quantity:
$$\mathbb E[\mathbb P[F_{x_i} \leq F_{x_1}\ \forall i = 2,\ldots, n | F_{x_1}]]$$
which I suspect to be equal to
$$\mathbb E[\prod\nolimits_{i=2}^n \mathbb P[F_{x_i} \leq F_{x_1}  | F_{x_1}]]. $$
However, without the outer expectation, the two terms do not seem to be equal since the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $F_{x_1}$ will contain many "large" sets $ \{ F_{x_1} \in \mathcal A \} $ conditioned on which $ \{ F_{x_2} \leq F_{x_1} \}, \ldots, \{ F_{x_n} \leq F_{x_1} \} $ will not be independent. How then can one formally argue for the factoring of events? In particular, the limiting case $\\{ F_{x_1} = c \\}$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$ which renders $F_{x_1}$ deterministic may be a set of measure zero.
